# How to define a surface which includes three coordinate axes?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, 3d, surfaces, connectedness, symmetric-functions

Imagine a plane with two crossing lines along $x$ and $y$ axes, and one line $y=x$. Now bend the $y=x$ line towards $z$ axis, dragging the part of that plane with it. When this line coincides with $z$ axis, you'll get a surface similar to this:

[image: surface]

But this one was generated from $z=\text{gaussian}_{0.3a}(x)$, i.e. if continued it'd not have $z$ full axis as its subset.

I'd like the surface to be:

1. Differentiable (except maybe at origin)
2. Symmetric in the sense that for each axis $A$ there existed a rotation which placed another axis $B$ to original location of $A$, leaving the surface unchanged.
3. Appeared as a single bent & stretched plane

How could I find (analytically define) such a surface (or a family of surfaces)?

Comment: The surface defined by $xy+xz+yz=0$ contains all three coordinate axes, is symmetric in $x$, $y$ and $z$ and is everywhere smooth except at the origin.

Comment: @User84559 thanks, your example is quite interesting. Still it's not quite what I'm looking for, I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: I have some ideas, but I don't have the means to graph implicit functions in three variables. Would you happen to know a (free) way to do so? 
Otherwise, I would suggest considering
$$X^2Y+Y^2Z+Z^2X\pm(X^2Z+Y^2X+Z^2Y).$$

Comment: @User84559 you can use http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=71dd9b48ff8928e726d4d21a5af243f3 to render ContourPlot3D of your equation (dunno if you can rotate it though). Your new example (putting $=0$ at the end) appears to work as I need with $+$ sign (and is just 3 crossing planes for $-$ sign). Could you turn this into an answer, so I could accept it, and also tell me how you constructed your examples?

Comment: If the $-$sign yields just $3$ crossing planes (which surprises me) and the $+$sign works, then ommiting the parenthesised part should also work.

And thanks for the link! Unfortunately my crummy old computer won't load any imagery, but I'll try it out elsewhere (:

Comment: @User84559 right, omitting the parenthesized part works, though the graph appears less symmetric when cut by cube. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP, an answer in stead of a comment. My answer is simply an intuitive approach to finding a single function with the desired properties, and does not at all hint at what the class of desired functions might look like.

As I know close to nothing about graphs or differentiable things, I restrict my attention to polynomials, things I am more familiar with. The symmetry requirement suggests considering a sum of a polynomial $f\in k[X,Y,Z]$ over its orbit under the action of $S_3$ or $A_3$, that is

$$F_S=\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}\sigma(f)\qquad\text{ or }\quad F_A=\sum_{\sigma\in A_3}\sigma(f).$$

The constructed polynomial is (almost) symmetric in $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, so for the graphs of $F_S$ and $F_A$ to contain the coordinate axes it suffices for $f$ to be zero on the $Z$-axis. Without loss of generality we may assume $f\in(XY)$. The simplest example would then be $f=XY$, yielding

$$F_A=XY+XZ+YZ=\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot F_S,$$

which is everywhere differentiable except at the origin. Unfortunately this does not meet the third requirement. To meet this requirement, it makes sense to consider a polynomial $f$ of odd degree.

The odd degree will make sure that the evaluation maps $k^2\ \longrightarrow\ k$ are surjective, for any of the three functions that $f$ induces on $k^2$ (corresponding to the three variables), resulting in a smoothly connected surface. Now the simplest example is $f=X^2Y$, yielding
$$F_A=X^2Y+Y^2Z+Z^2X,$$
$$F_S=X^2Y+X^2Z+Y^2X+Y^2Z+Z^2X+Z^2Y,$$
which apparently do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the monkey saddle, equation $z = x^3 - 3 xy^2 $. Note that this graph has 6-fold rotational symmetry, and along the lines $y=0$, $y= \frac{\sqrt 3} 2 x$, and $y = \frac{ - \sqrt 3} 2 x$, increases like $z = r^3$. Hence, taking the cube root, $z = \sqrt[3]{x^3 - 3 xy^2}$ gives us a function which is linear along 3 equally spaced directions.

Compare this with the coordinate $x,y,z$-axes when viewed from the point $(1,1,1)$; this also looks linear along 3 equally spaced directions, but with slope $1/2$ in these directions. Hence it follows that the function
$ z = \dfrac 12 \cdot \sqrt[3]{x^3 - 3xy^2},$
rotated appropriately, is your desired function.

Comment: The function, intersected with these 3 planes, gives three lines symmetric about 120 degree rotation about the z-axis. The factor of 1/2 makes them mutually perpendicular so a final rotation will finish the job.

Comment: The axes still don't appear mutually orthogonal: parametrically $(t,0,0.5t), (t,-\sqrt3t,-t), (t,\sqrt3t,-t)$. Or do I look at the wrong axes?

Comment: My factor of $1/2$ might be off, I'll have to check that a bit later as it's pretty late though. If not $1/2$ then certainly some other constant will suffice.